# React roles based route accesss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've an application in React 17 and router version is 6, I already know basic authentication and authorization, but what I'm struggling is with, there are certain paths which are allowed to the user, and others are not.
here is my code structure

```
import React from 'react'

function App() {
    let userRoles = [
        "products/list",
        "products/add",
        "products/update",
        "products/delete",
        "action/list",
        "action/add",
        "action/edit"
    ]
    return (
        <Route>
            < Route path="/action" element={< Action />} />
            < Route path="/edit-action" element={< EditActions />} />
            < Route path="/add-actions" element={< AddActions />} />
            
            < Route path="/products" element={< Products />} />
            < Route path="/edit-product" element={< AddProducts />} />
            < Route path="/add-products" element={< AddProducts />} />

            {/* Not allowed to the user */}
            < Route path="/broker-firm" element={< BrokerFirm />} />
            < Route path="/add-broker-firm" element={< AddBrokerFirm />} />
            < Route path="/edit-broker-firm" element={< EditBrokerFirm />} />
        </Route>
    )
}

export default App
```

What is want it that if a user tries to navigate to any route that is not allowed, it should stay on the same page, and show a toast notification that you're not allowed to this route.

I can show the toast message with `toast.error("Some error message")`
But I'm not getting to making to make it work, like this.

What I already tried is wrapping the route inside the condition like this

```
{userRoles.includes("product/list") && < Route path="/products" element={< Products />} />}
```

but the problem with this approach is that I can't show the error message to the user, since that React Router simple doesn't know anything about that route, it simply will not generate that route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to do what you want. Instead of checking it in the `app.js` you can check it in the `individual components`.

You can pass the data to the `component` and there you can check it if the `user` is allowed to access it or not.

```
if(!userRoles.includes("product/list")) {
 navigate('/')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know this is a good solution, but I'll have to check in each component, is there anyway to escape this and still achieve what I want

Comment: I don't know if there is any other way. But I have used this solution and it works pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You simply wrap the routes that you wish to restrict with an auth validating component.
Their docs have a really good example, [docs explanation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth), [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src/App.tsx)